# resampling from a frequency distribution (histogram) to test for significance

Tags: r, permutation-test, resampling

Suppose I have count data on brands and the number of toys they make.

```
toycount <- read.table( "toys_per_brand.txt", header = F)
toycount

      Toys       Brand
1       1       brand1
2       1       brand2
3       2       brand3
4       6       brand4
5      13       brand5
6       1       brand6
7       2       brand7
8       2       brand8
9       2       brand9
.
.
10637   3      brand10637

toycount <- toycount$V1
hist(toycount)
```

[image]
If I want to resample from this data random draws (say 99999 of them) of 89 toys and count the distribution of the number of brands sampled to see if 80 brands is more than expected by chance, how would I do this? Essentially I want to test whether my sampling of the toys was uniform against an alternative that it was not uniform (possible alternatives are: 'choose bigger sized brands with higher probability', or 'choose smaller size brands with higher probability' etc)

I have:

```
 set.seed(5)
    test.value = 80
    toy_pool = c(1:sum(toycount))
    toy_sample = 89 
    perm = 99999

output = rep(NA, times = length(1:perm))
for(i in 1:perm){
  brands_sampled = sample(toy_pool,size = toy_sample)
  output[i]=length((brands_sampled))
}
hist(output, col = "blue", breaks = seq(0,89, by = 1), xlab = "brands sampled", main = "Permutation test")
abline(v=test.value, col = "black", lwd = 4)

(sum(output > test.value) + 1) / (perm + 1)
```

I know this is way off but any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Because you haven't provided information to indicate chance plays any role in your data, there's no way to answer your question.  If your data are a sample of some larger population, then please say so and explain how it was obtained.